# We had problems activating your account

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

When email activate this error message "We had problems activating your account"

any problems my activate code..???
**code give below..**

**'activate.php'**

```
<?php 
    include 'core/init.php';
    logged_in_redirect();
    include 'includes/overall/header.php';

    if (isset($_GET['success']) === true && empty($_GET['success']) === true) {
    ?>
        <h2>Thanks, we've activated your account....</h2>
        <p>You're free to Log in!</p>

    <?php

    } else if (isset($_GET['email'], $_GET['email_code']) === true) {

        $email      = trim($_GET['email']);
        $email_code   = trim($_GET['email_code']);

        if (email_exists($email) === false) {
            $errors[] = 'Oops, something went wrong and we could\'t find that email address';
        } else if (activate($email, $email_code) === false) {
            $errors[] = 'We had problems activating your account';
        }

        if (empty($errors) === false) {
        ?>
            <h2>Ooops...</h2>
        <?php
            echo output_errors($errors);        
        } else {
            header('Location: activate.php?success');
            exit();
        }

    } else {
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit();
    }

    include 'includes/overall/footer.php'; 
?>
```

**Email link code given below:**
**'user.php'**

Answer (score 1):

The `activate` function returns `false`. Make sure you call it in the correct way and that it works as expected.

Comment: function activate($email, $email_code) {
 $email   = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
 $email_code = mysql_real_escape_string($email_code);
 
 if (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `email` AND `email_code` = '$email_code' AND `active` = 0"), 0) == 1) {
  mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `active` = 1 WHERE `email` = '$email'");
  return true;  
 } else {
  return false;
 }
}


please check this code..??

Comment: I think you should do some basic troubleshooting yourself. Check that your SQL queries works as expected by running them manually in a SQL program. Check with `mysql_error` for error messages.